# How to set Smart Banner for Android app?

Tags: android, admob, banner, smartbanner

How can I get "smart banner" in spite of simple "banner" in my android app? . I have tried the following code but in vain. It is not showing any banner instead.

```
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The AdView that you are setting Size and UnitID on is not the AdView that you are calling loadAd on. You are setting the ad info on an AdView that you instantiating in code, and then calling loadAd on a view that you are referencing from XML.

```
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Then what is the correct method. I am not clear enough to implement what you are saying. 

If I delete the following code line then smart banner appears but with the changing of orientation or loading of new ad it goes back to simple "BANNER"
 
 adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

I have already set AdSize SMART_BANNER both in xml and class file but why is this occuring I am not clear. Would you please help me?

Comment: In the manifest , I used

      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: Their documentation states that you must either set both the adSize and UnitId in xml OR code, but NOT both. Your ad should not be changing it's size when you change orientation unless you are doing that somewhere. I've edited my answer with the correct code.